# How to create an editing-mode-viewController that gets displayed when UITableViewRowAction is pressed?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

In a swift to-do app, there is one UITableViewController and a normal UIViewController. In the UIViewController called "AddToDoVC," there is a text box for the todo's name and a title label (viewTitle) "Add ToDo." Now, the add button gets pressed and it saves the toDo and displays the name on the "ToDos" UITableViewController. Now, I have inserted an UITableViewRowAction called "editAction." When this edit button is pressed on the tableView, it goes to the "AddToDoVC" and I want that viewController to change a bit so that is becomes an edit mode, where, for instance, the title "Add ToDo" gets changed to "Edit ToDo," or the name textField automatically becomes the saved toDo's name (I'm using Realm Swift to save, if that may help). Now, how could I do that? Here's what I have written so far, but it always gives me the error "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value."

In "ToDos" UITableViewController:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {

    //Edit
    let editAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: UITableViewRowActionStyle.Normal, title: "Edit") {(editAction, indexPath) -> Void in

        //Shows AddTaskVC when "Edit" is pressed
        let editTaskVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("addTaskVC") as! AddTaskVC
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(editTaskVC, animated: true)

        //Changing the viewTitle's text from "Add Task" to "Edit Task" as it is now in an "Edit" mode -> this doesn't do anything other than give me the error "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"
        editTaskVC.viewTitle.text = "Edit Task"

    }

    //Return edit action
    return [editAction]

}
```

How could this edit-mode be achieved? Thank you in advance.

Comment: issue resolved?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Setting value directly to label. Define a String `str` in the `AddToDoVC` and assign that string value to the `Label` in the `viewDidLoad()`.

Currently value for label will not get set because label is not being drawn in the view controller and you are assigning value to it.